# Burg + UEFI + Win 8 multiboot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, burg

**Intro:**

After some trial and error I've managed to install Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on my Win 8 preinstalled Lenovo Ideapad Y500.
So far I've had two problems:

- Grub detected the windows 8 install as a recovery install (already fixed this by adding a 15_windows file with a correct boot entry)
- Brightness doesn't work. (Not too bothered by this.)

**The problem**

I don't really like how grub looks though. So I want to install BURG.
But Win8 is under UEFI (and the bios is set to Legacy support with the "UEFI first" option set).
I've read about how this would work with Arch, but how about ubuntu? I'd prefer pre-packaged burg (ppa's are fine with me).
Could somebody tell me how to setup burg with UEFI and a custom entry (and, possibly, how to hide the other entries in a submenu of sorts)?

Thanks to everybody who is willing to help!

**EDIT:** 
In reply of @oldfred's answer, I was already aware of rEFInd, but my system failed the checks for (U)EFI mode from the documentation (although /sys/firmware/efi exists with plenty of subdirectories and files) and I *know* my win8 install boots uefi mode.
And I've grown attached to the burg theme I use on my other non-uefi systems (3 laptops and 3 desktops), as well as the fact that Arch has a EFI-compat version of burg in it's repos.

Comment: Care to share the theme that you've grown attached to? Burg looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Burg has not been maintained for a long time, and I am not sure it will work with UEFI at all. Standard grub is grub-pc for BIOS and grub-efi for UEFI systems.

But with UEFI you can install a UEFI boot manager -rEFInd. I have not done it but the creator does post in this forum.

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Alternative efi boot Manager for UEFI limited systems:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/UEFI_Bootloaders#Using_rEFInd

More info on secure boot - Ubuntu's shim may need changing to work with Refind

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html

Comment: See my edit to the OP

Answer (score 0):

This was too long for a comment so I'm posting this as an answer with more details.

Edit: Since BURG appears to be an outdated fork of GRUB and this question was about UEFI please take note of the following USN/CVE: [USN-2836-1: GRUB vulnerability (CVE-2015-8370)](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2836-1/)

---

Please back up that *"fact"* with a link to the burg package in the Arch repository. I couldn't find it, only themes in the AUR and Arch Wiki redirects to GRUB with no mention of BURG in the entire article. The Google Code project links to mostly outdated content giving the impression that this project has been abandoned long ago. Someone on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/burg-devel/CRwtyUFUUvg) was talking about a netfs module for the EFI platform and the [burg-mkimage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg#Build_and_install_.28efi.29) command looks very similar to grub's which I use in [my top uefi answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581). Pulling upstream code to create the image and put it on the ESP doesn't appear to be a difficult task, I agree with that. The missing link however is to find the current upstream. A [PPA exists](https://askubuntu.com/q/460551/40581) from someone who appears to have been a contributor or developer with a lengthy warning in his profile: `I DO NOT TAKE REQUESTS on what is put in my Repos. …` Looking at the source package, it appears to be just GRUB from 2010 with undocumented changes and the package just comes out of nowhere with no reference to a code repository. Further the typical files like `TODO`, `README` and `NEWS` are from GRUB not BURG. Sure you could try to go back in the GRUB source at that time and do a diff, but I don't use BURG, a user interested in BURG should do that.

Please tell me where I'm wrong here or where I may have overlooked something. It's entirely possible that someone else has taken over this project and maintains a Git repository, but from all I can find this project looks like abandonware to me and *currently* so sloppily documented that nobody should have started to use it in the first place.

**With that time spend on investigation and until further evidence shows up I'm going to flag all future questions about BURG as primarily opinion based or EOL.**

Final note, though it should have been obvious: users of AskUbuntu are not responsible to do the communication work that active project members of a particular project should have been doing or keeping disorganized or abandonware projects alive.