# How to install BURG on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: repository, bootloader, 17.04, error-handling, burg

I get a package error in BURG on Ubuntu 17.04 as they aren't in Zesty Zapus repositories yet. Can anyone tell me how to install them?

Step by step if you can.
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of : https://askubuntu.com/questions/326580/burg-uefi-win-8-multiboot Burg is obsolete & most systems now are UEFI and can use rEFInd if a gui type boot loader requried.